# Is there any apple API that we can get configuration details of mac like RAM And Processor

Tags: macos

We are getting full model name like MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013) from **https://support-sp.apple.com/sp/product?cc=(last 4 digits of serial number)** by passing serial number .

Is there any apple API available that we can get details like RAM, Processor,Disk Capacity by passing laptop serial number.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Probably the `system_profiler`, to get hardware details you could use for example:

```
$ system_profiler SPHardwareDataType
Hardware:

    Hardware Overview:

      Model Name: MacBook Pro
      Model Identifier: MacBookPro14,1
      Processor Name: Intel Core i7
      Processor Speed: 2.5 GHz
      Number of Processors: 1
      Total Number of Cores: 2
      L2 Cache (per Core): 256 KB
      L3 Cache: 4 MB
      Memory: 16 GB
      Boot ROM Version: MBP141.0173.B00
      SMC Version (system): 2.43f6
      Serial Number (system): C02WXXXX123
      Hardware UUID: 0d8650d3-aa68-4435-934d-6ed5c540194b
```

To get a list of more datatypes you could use:

```
$ system_profiler -listDataTypes
```

Comment: I know that system_profiler gives us all the details . But without running any commands in terminal(bash script), I want to capture the details directly from apple API. Is there any APIs for this?